# Use of $.extend function in jQuery with multiple objecs

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and I want to know about $.extend() function in jQuery.

Can anyone please explain the difference between following statements?

```
$.extend(true,ob1,ob2);

$.extend(true,{},ob1,ob2);

$.extend(true,ob1,{},ob2);

$.extend(true,ob1,ob2,{});
```

Thanks,

Anand

Comment: see here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best explained with a sample

```
var firstObject = {
    "hello": "jonkers",
};
var secondObject = {
    "stradivarius": "bonkers"
};
console.log(firstObject);
>> Object {hello: "jonkers"} 
$.extend(firstObject, secondObject);
console.log(firstObject);
>> Object {hello: "jonkers", stradivarius: "bonkers"}
```

But what does the `true` part mean? It's a boolean value that tells the `$.extend` function that a *deep copy* is supposed to take place.

A deep copy, you say!

There are two different types of "copying" when it comes to objects which applies to many languages and not just JavaScript and that's `shallow` and `deep`.
Shallow copy is when you just take the references to that object (and all it contains) and make a duplicate leading to the values changed in `copy_object` is reflected in `original_object`.
A deep copy is an actual brand spanking new object which you can manipulate three ways to sunday without it affecting the `original_object`.

The last example you're wanting to know about is the exact same call except it'll take several more objects to put in your first object.
So the api call would be

```
$.extend(true, firstObject, secondObject, third, fourth, n-objects);
```

Reading more about this can be done

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

http://blog.imaginea.com/deep-copy-in-javascript/

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with the definition of the `extend`function:

`When two or more object arguments are supplied to`$.extend()`, properties from all of the objects are added to the target object. Arguments that are null or undefined are ignored.`

Now lets see your example codes:

```
1. $.extend(true,ob1,ob2);
```

The target is ob1, this one is going to add the ob2 arguments to its parameters.

```
2. $.extend(true,{},ob1,ob2);
```

The target is a new object (defined with {}). This new object will have the arguments from both objects (ob1 and ob2).

```
3. $.extend(true,ob1,{},ob2);
```

The target is ob1, it will add the arguments from a new object (it doesn't make sence) and the object ob2. *Does it work with the new object parameter?*

```
4. $.extend(true,ob1,ob2,{});
```

The target is ob1, it will add the arguments from the object ob2 and from a new object (it doesn't make sence either). *Does it work with the new object parameter?*